# How to change the row color in a DataGrid view

Tags: .net

I have a console application to which a form is added.

This form has a datagrid view in it with all the properties left to default.

In Program.cs I have this code in the Main method:

```
CompanyActions objCompanyActions = new CompanyActions();

List<Company> analyzedData = new List<Company>();

List<Company> CompaniesFromExternalSource = objCompanyActions.GetExternalCompanyData(@"company.csv");

analyzedData =  objCompanyActions.Compare(CompaniesFromExternalSource);
AnalysisForm objAnalysisForm = new AnalysisForm();

objAnalysisForm.ShowAnalysisData(analyzedData);
Application.Run(objAnalysisForm);
```

In the form I have this code:

```
public void ShowAnalysisData(List<Company> analysisData)
{
     analysisGridView.DataSource = analysisData;

     UpdateGridStyle();

}
```

and

```
  private void UpdateGridStyle()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in analysisGridView.Rows)
        {
            string RowType = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            if (RowType == "Insert")
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
              //  row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else if (RowType == "Update")
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
               // row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
              //  row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
```

This doesn't work. The grid still retains the default white background for each row?
what am I doing wrong here?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're calling the method to change the background color at the wrong time. Try placing it in CellFormatting like this:

```
private void analysisGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = analysisGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string RowType = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    if (RowType == "Insert")
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        //  row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else if (RowType == "Update")
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        // row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
        else
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        //  row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep that worked but there is a noticable lag when the grid is scrolled! Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: If you scroll all the way down and then back up, does the grid still lag?

Comment: Also, it may be worth just doing this using jquery, since you're just looking at the value of cells rather than some server-side value. It may prove to be the quicker solution.

Comment: @ Alec Sanger yes it does lag, infact everytime I scroll it's like repainting the whole thing.

Comment: Could you try swapping out analysisGridView_CellFormatting with analysisGridView_RowPrePaint and see if you get better performance?

Comment: I put a break point on the CellFormatting method and it get's called for all the rows every time the grid is clicked for scrolling or no scrolling. Will investigate this.

Comment: If you are binding the data, you can probably perform the color change on DataBind as well. You just can't call the color change AFTER the rows have been painted.